# Creating user profile that is accessible application-wide

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm implementing a very basic login system, not actually using any outofthebox login controls. My database contains the following tables:

UserProfiles: contains details of the user 
UserSecurityRoles: contains the security roles for each user

In my asp.net application i use the following code to login a user :

```
protected void Logon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_BLSecurity.verifyUser(UserName.Text, UserPass.Text))
            {
                Response.Redirect("../Default.aspx");

            }
            else
            {
                Msg.Text = "Invalid credentials. Please try again.";
            }
        }
```

Once a user is verified, I need to store the information about him contained in UserProfiles and UserSecurityRoles in my web application so that i can access this data from each form i have and set permissions based on it.

Any ideas how i can perform this ?

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if something is not clear !: )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom class for an example `SessionContext` in which you will save all the needed data on login. After that you can make class which every UI.Page inherits. In this class you will have `SessionContext` property.

```
    public SessionContext USession
    {
        get
        {
            if (base.Session["_USRSESS"] != null)
                return (BO.SessionContext)base.Session[_USRSESS];
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Session["_USRSESS"] = value;
        }
    }
```

When you need this the user data you will call this property in every page. Saving one custom class here will give possibility to put everything you want in the session and don't need to remember multiple session variable.

**EDIT:**

If you have BasicPage class

```
public class BasicPage : System.Web.UI.Page 
{

    public SessionContext USession
    {
        get
        {
            if (base.Session["_USRSESS"] != null)
                return (BO.SessionContext)base.Session[_USRSESS];
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Session["_USRSESS"] = value;
        }
    }
}

public partial class _Default : BasicPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

See that aspx.pages inherits `BasicPage` and `BasicPage` inherits `UI.Page`.

When you are redirecting to Default page, you will need something like that:

```
            SessionContext resSession = new SessionContext();

            // I'm giving you example with standard bool property. You can put class property if you want.
            resSession.IsAdmin = Convert.ToInt32(userRow["IsAdmin"]) == 1;
            // this is Guid property for the User primary key, if you are using integer for primary key the property should be int.
            resSession.UserID = (Guid)userRow["ID"];

            BasicPage page = this.Page as BasicPage;
            page.UserSession = session;

            Response.Redirect("../Default.aspx");
```

Comment: Thank you, can you please elaborate more, on how to access the session from the parent class ? I'm trying to use "base.Session..." but i'm getting "object does not contain a definition for session"

Comment: @user3340627 just a second, I will edit my question.

Comment: @user3340627 you can check the full answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the UserProfilesData in the Session. Each user has a unique session associated with him.

```
protected void Logon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_BLSecurity.VerifyUser(UserName.Text, UserPass.Text))
    {
        Session["currentUserProfile"] = GetUserProfile();
        Response.Redirect("../Default.aspx");

    }
    else
    {
        Msg.Text = "Invalid credentials. Please try again.";
    }
}
```

Then, whenever you need the UserProfile object, you can get it from the Session using the currentUserProfile key.

```
var userProfile = (UserProfile)Session["currentUserProfile"];
```